# Huge Data Base in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I had about 20,000,000 records 
in a table (random data), and then I added empty column to that table...
but when I update that table to fill that column, the process was broken down..
I tried to use the cursor and the index but no results..
do you have any fast solution or any alternative solution?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Do the UPDATE in chunks of perhaps 1000 to 10000 rows?

Comment: Please post some more details; a complete table structure ( with indexes, constraints, etc), the error you're having, the query you're using and its explain plan could help

Comment: Yes and then commit but no result

Comment: If it's just appearing to do nothing - no error but doesn't return - maybe you have uncommitted changes in another session? Otherwise you'll need to provide a lot more information to get any useful help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the fastest way would be to create new_table as select * from existing table, and then inside the select statment of CTAS,  calculate the value of the new column. After that,  you can rename old table to something like table_bckp, then rename new table to the original table name, and then apply constraints, indexes, and other scripts previously saved from old table definitions.